# Debian: Brightness control does not work

Tags: debian, grub, amd-graphics, brightness, acer

I have just installed Debian on my Acer Aspire laptop; it has a Ryzen 5 CPU and a Radeon Vega AMD card. All is going pretty much fine, only problem is **I can't change the screen brightness!**

I have tried with the dedicated buttons on the keyboard, I have tried from the bar in the `settings` menu, nothing; the slider moves but the brightness of the screen remains unchanged. This is driving me crazy..

I have also tried going into `/etc/default/grub` and changed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` value, but still no progress. Here is my `grub` file:

[image]

I have read online that adding `acpi_backlight=video` should fix the problem, however it didn't for me...
What is going on? How can I fix my brightness? I want to be able to use the brightness slider or the keyboard buttons to change it!

---

**EDIT:** Wanting desperately to take control over my screen's brightness I have just tried using `xbacklight` but it also does nothing!! I installed it, set a new brightness percentage, and it simply does nothing! What is going on? Nothing seems to work..

Comment: Could you find a solution for this problem?